# Unable to View Household members on Contact Dashboard

Tags: drupal, relationships, accessibility

CiviCRM was recently upgraded from 3.5.x to 4.6.36
I can see Household members when logged in as an Admin on Drupal 7.50 website.
When I am logged in as an authenticated user, 
I don't see the Relationship on contact dashboard

What would be the appropriate permission I need to set to enable authenticated users to view Relationships(household members)?

Comment: Each relationship has permissions that allow contacts to view & edit the related person - if you are on a recent version (5.x) then you can manage those permissions a bit better through https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermissions extension (in general if you have just upgraded you should probably upgrade through to the latest version - although there was a commitment to do security releases for 4.6 to the end of 2018.)

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of CiviCRM, if you go to Contact Summary Page, Relationships tab, and edit a relationship, there are options there for each side of the relationship to edit, view or have no permission for the other contact. I'm pretty sure this predated 4.6.